# Create a dataframe from one dictionary and remove a specific character

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know if it is possible to create a dataframe from two dictionaries.
I get two dictionaries like this:

```
dict= {'MO': ['N-2', 'N-8', 'N-7', 'N-6', 'N-9'], 'MO2': ['N0-6'], 'MO3': ['N-2']}
```

My result will be like this :

```
     ID        NUM
0    MO       'N-2', 'N-8', 'N-7', 'N-6', 'N-9'
1    MO2      'N0-6'
2    MO3      'N-2'
```

I try to obtain this result but in the column with the value I get [] and I can't remove it

```
liste_id=list(dict.keys())
liste_num=list(dict.values())
df = pandas.DataFrame({'ID':liste_id,'NUM':liste_num})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge the values in the dictionary into a string, before creating the dataframe; this ensures the arrays are of the same length

```
pd.DataFrame([(key, ", ".join(value))
             for key, value in dicts.items()], 
             columns = ['ID', 'NUM'])



    ID       NUM
0   MO  N-2, N-8, N-7, N-6, N-9
1   MO2 N0-6
2   MO3 N-2
```